# Is there a way to use the sum function in XPATH 1.0 so it will work on sub-nodes in the XML file?

Tags: xml, path, sum

[image: XML Code]

I am trying to sum the weight of only the BOL lines which have a property line value of 095 in the Propertly Line section.

Desired outcome would be a sum to total the weight  but only for those lines  that have a PropertyLine icsp.prodcat = 095

I can sum the lines who's icsp.prodcat have a 095 in them by using
sum(/dsBillOfLading/tt-BOLheader/tt-BOLline/PropertyLine[@FieldName = 'icsp.prodcat'][(FieldValue = 095)]/FieldValue)

but what I am struggling with is totaling the weight for only those lines where the above value (prodcat) = 095

Any help would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above. All within the question, no images.

Comment: I can't copy and paste from your XML so I'm not going to try and be accurate, but it will be something like `sum(BOL[PropertyLine='095'])`

Comment: Thanks you Michael Kay. Yitzhak, sorry I tried inserting the image but I will try to put more information in next time desired output etc.

Comment: XML code, not pictures of code, will make it easier for people to help you

Comment: I've made an edit with current values and things I've been trying